# Hyperlink within a button

Tags: wpf, xaml, kinect

I have a a href hyperlink in my application which on click opens a link in a built in wpf web browser control.  However, how would I go about putting this inside a button control? I have tried the following:

```
<Button ID="button2="30" Width="100">
<a href>........</a href>
</Button>
```

I am doing a kinect application, i have button behaviours set up similar to an xbox selection animation.

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx) element.

Typical usage would be:

```
<Button x:Name="btnNavigate" Width="100">
    <Hyperlink x:Name="lnkGoogle" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com"
        RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" >
        Click Here.
    </Hyperlink>
</Button>
```

The RequestNavigate event handler is required if the Hyperlink element is not nested within a navigation host control (directly or indirectly). The event handler can be defined like this:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

HTH...